# How to use QtCreator to statically link FLTK libraries

Tags: qt-creator, static-linking, fltk

I am using Qt Creator (Qt 5.0.3 on Ubuntu 14) for a normal c++ project where I am using FLTK libraries. i want to link FLTK statically to my executable. How do I do that using Qt Creator( I am not using any of Qt libraries, just a normal c++ project with FLTK)

Comment: For that you need basically to build a static version of the FLTK library, and in your C++ project you link against that library. I am sure any IDE for C++ can configure such a project...

Comment: Are you using QtCreator `.pro` file for your project, or is QtCreator just an editor for you ?

Comment: I am using QtCreator .pro file but I am not using Qt libraries. @prajmus

Answer (score 0):

You can add suitable LIBS += -l... and INCLUDEPATH += /usr/... to your .pro